# reading json file into Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read a json file into Spark DataFrame, but I'm getting the whole file as one row and one column I'm trying to split it to multiple columns:

```
df = spark.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles("HW2-DataSets/docs/output-0.json").values())
df.show()
```

and this is the output i'm getting from running this line of code :

```
+--------------------+
|              Images|
+--------------------+
|[[ricky4, 1634180...|
+--------------------+
```

this is the schema for the DataFrame that was created :

```
    root
 |-- Images: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Z4ah9SemQjX2cKN187pX: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- artist: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- download_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- file_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key_words: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tagged: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Z552dVXF5vp80bAajYrn: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- artist: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- download_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- file_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key_words: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tagged: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Z598cIDb79GPrC6VXbTb: struct (nullable = true)
           ....
```

my goal is to put each one of the objects inside images in one row and separated columns
which means for example "Z4ah9SemQjX2cKN187pX" with it values : artist,created_at... in the first row and "Z552dVXF5vp80bAajYrn" in the second row etc.

I'm very new to spark every comment will help , thanks.

**Update**

```
{
  "Images": {
    "Z4ah9SemQjX2cKN187pX": {
      "artist": "ricky4",
      "file_name": "mermaid_by_ricky4_d59jfzw-fullview.jpg",
      "created_at": 1634180503921,
      "description": "Hi folks! This is my latest work! So glad to be a part of the calendar project from my friend Dee  More details here! :thumb322291755: artistsforacure.deviantart.com… Inspired by: CLOCK DVA - Return to blue www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjfxI2…All resources: my own! Other purple artworks",
      "key_words": [
        "dark",
        "digital",
        "evil",
        "fantasy",
        "fishes",
        "lady",
        "light",
        "magic",
        "mermaid",
        "ocean",
        "sea",
        "utopia",
        "reflections"
      ],
      "source": "https://www.deviantart.com/",
      "title": "Mermaid",
      "tagged": false,
      "download_url": "",
      "id": "Z4ah9SemQjX2cKN187pX"
    },
    "Z552dVXF5vp80bAajYrn": {
```

Comment: I have also tried to use this line of code , 
df = spark.read.json("HW2-DataSets/docs/output-0.json"), but getting the same results

Comment: Can you share how does JSON file looks like?

Comment: @RahulKumar yes I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can first of all read the json file using multiline option and get it as single column in the dataframe variable and after that you can use the select statement on the dataframe variable using columnname.* and it will give you a dataframe with one row where each row will have columns with single value as in your json.

Code as below:

```
#read the json file
df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("HW2-DataSets/docs/output-0.json")
#used the select statement to see the output you want
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1 = df.select(col("Images.*"))
#do df1.show() to see the output
# I am using Databricks so I do display(df1)

#Convert Columns to rows (Updated)
from itertools import chain

m = create_map(list(chain(*(
        (lit(c), col(c)) for c in df1.columns))))

df2 = df1.withColumn('map', m)\
  .select(explode('map')).drop('map')
```

You can see the output as below :

[image]

Comment: I tried this but now I get a data frame that that every column is the object , I have added this line of code to your code : 
print((df_images.count(), len(df_images.columns)))
# prints (1,444)
which means it made a column of every object , I was trying to make it 444 rows and the columns are the keys for every object( artist , created_at...) , do you have any idea how to that ?

Comment: See the updated answer to get the result that you are expecting.

Comment: I'm getting an exception in the last line of code.

AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'map('Z4ah9SemQjX2cKN187pX', `Z4ah9SemQjX2cKN187pX`, 'Z552dVXF5vp80bAajYrn',1XH4MCAOefT#8908, Images#7998.Z6RxIsCeAmZW2s7FpFfh AS Z6RxIsCeAmZW2s7FpFfh#8909, Images#7998.Z6VD11n6TuLxFpwuBnHt AS Z6VD11n6TuLxFpwuBnHt#8910, Images#7998.Z6f7Ia2ZSwUnc6coiL5u AS Z6f7Ia2ZSwUnc6coiL5u#8911, Images#7998.Z6jsJ6GHGqCzVtYrWcvJ AS Z6jsJ6GHGqCzVtYrWcvJ#8912, ... 420 more fields]
   +- Relation[Images#7998] json
,

Comment: at which line do you get the exception? Is there something different in the actual data that you are working on because based on the sample data that is present in the question it works fine.

Comment: at df2 line , I don't believe so I have posted one of the objects from the data.

Comment: There might be something wrong with the data. you could just exclude the select statement from the last line and just run `df2 = df1.withColumn('map',m)` and see if t works fine or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240009/discussion-between-nikunj-kakadiya-and-mahajna).